# Bulk insert to MySQL max_allowed_packet reached using Sequelize

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to Bulk Insert into my MySQL database using Sequelize.

```
let insertedData = await db.productInventory.bulkCreate(productsDetails);
```

`productDetails` object is supposed to have >10k objects to be inserted all at once.

Currently with only 2k rows, I am getting the following error:

> Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

However it works fine with 1000 rows.

I want to know what is the best practice/solution to fix this error.

I know of two solutions right now.

- I can either increase the maximum allowed packet size to 1GB and it
  might work.
- I can send the 10k rows in chunks of 1k and query the db 10 times
  synchronously.

Probably there is other ways to achieve this.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: i dont think there is any other way. you manage to find the answers to your solution already.

Comment: which one is the better one among the above two?